# Screen lock not working in Moto z play

Tags: lock-screens, stock-android, pattern-lock

I recently got into an issue with my Moto z play screen lock. Pressing the power button doesn't lock the screen. I have enabled pattern lock option for screen lock. But still only after booting up it asks for the pattern. But later on when I lock the screen by pressing power button , I can unlock by just swiping the screen. Anyone knows what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was be because of the Google smart-lock feature. The on-body detection was on in settings->security->smart lock
. I Turned off the on-body detection and its fine now

Answer (score 0):

It could be (depending on your Android version) there is an extra option called

> powerbutton locks immediately

if that is not selected it could be the problem. You could crawl the security settings for more options.

Comment: `power button instantly locks` this option I have already enabled